# Order array by name of enum instead of value

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have an enumeration:

```
export enum Foo{
    AA= 0,
    ZZ= 1,
    AB= 2,
    ER = 5
}
```

I want my `Bars`, which contain the `enum` as a property `foo`, to be sorted on the name of the enum (AA, AB, ER, ZZ), and not on the numerical value (0, 1, 2, 5).

I'm using lodash to help me but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
const orderedBars = _.orderBy(unorderedBars, 'foo');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) them based on the string value:

```
unorderedBars.sort((a,b) => Foo[a.foo].localeCompare(Foo[b.foo]))
```

[Demo on Typescript playgorund](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20AA%3D%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ZZ%3D%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20AB%3D%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ER%20%3D%205%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20array%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20foo%3A%20Foo.ER%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20foo%3A%20Foo.AA%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20foo%3A%20Foo.AB%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20foo%3A%20Foo.ZZ%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aarray.sort((a%2Cb)%20%3D%3E%20Foo%5Ba.foo%5D.localeCompare(Foo%5Bb.foo%5D))%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20displaying%20on%20the%20DOM%0D%0Aconst%20pre%20%3D%20document.createElement(%22pre%22)%3B%0D%0Apre.innerHTML%20%3D%20JSON.stringify(array%2C%20null%2C%203)%0D%0Apre.innerHTML%20%2B%3D%20JSON.stringify(array.map(a%20%3D%3E%20Foo%5Ba.foo%5D)%2C%20null%2C%203)%20%2F%2F%20to%20see%20the%20string%20values%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(pre)%3B%0D%0A) (Click on "Run")

If the property is string and you want to sort it based on the numerical value, you could [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it like this:

```
unorderedBars.sort((a, b) => Foo[a.foo] - Foo[b.foo])
```